# How to stop windows form from closing but hide upon clicking the X?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to have a click event that will open another form. I don't want the user to be able to close this window because I get the following exception when the click event is executed again.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Form2'.'

I'm not sure if I'm implementing this correctly or there's a better way of doing this.

**Form1**

---

```
public Form2 f = new Form2();

private void Btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f.Show();
}
```

**Form2**

---

```
private bool allowClose = false; 
private void Btnclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allowClose = true;
    this.Hide();
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!allowClose)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Why not move the creation of the form inside the click handler?

Comment: '*I'm not sure if I'm implementing this correctly or there's a better way of doing this.*' Are you facing with any problem/exception or are you looking just for code review?

Comment: @RezaAghaei - The `ObjectDisposedException` seems to be the OP's issue.

Comment: There's a better way. Don't store an **instance** of an object that surely will be disposed of at some point. Create a new one when you need it. Do you need to access the new instance from the Form (the class) that created it? Assign the **new** instance to a Field (or a private property of Form1 or another class you use to manage UI objects creation/destruction). A Form is a class as any other: as any other class, you can't blindly rely on an instance of it when you know that instance is bound to be disposed of. This is the wrong part: `public Form2 f = new Form2();`.

Comment: In `Btnsearch_Click`, create the new instance of Form2 and show it. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of form2 should be created within the event

```
private void Btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to [Form.OnClosing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047475/how-do-i-catch-the-event-of-exiting-a-winforms-application) and set the [Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel?view=netframework-4.8) property on the event args that are passed to the handler. This will tell the runtime to cancel the close event.

Since the event is getting canceled, you'll have to hide the form yourself (using `Hide()`, of course).

```
private void Form1_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to prevent the problem that the OP is seeing.

Comment: It seems to me it's a logic issue around the value of `allowClose`.

Comment: It does prevent OP's problem, but now we're dealing with an instance-scoped form (aka could create many instances over time) that looks like it closes, but actually never does. It should be noted that such forms must be explicitly terminated via `Form.Dispose`, and probably explicitly exit your application with `Environment.Exit`, otherwise you can end up with memory leaks and immortal invisible forms, neither of which are ever good things (though admittedly don't always cause problems).

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.

It's generally more efficient, in the FormClosing event, to hide the form and cancel the event, but this can require extra logic.

Unless you have some expensive code that needs to run when the form is created, this probably doesn't matter, and it'll be easier to simply allow the form to close normally.

Either way, all you particularly need to do, is throw some safeguards into the btnSearch handler, so that it can appropriately respond to the state of form `f`;

```
public Form2 f;
public void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f == null || f.IsDisposed || f.Disposing) f = new Form2(...);
    f.Show();
}
```